# Entity Framework + Autofac: How to properly reload mappings / configurations?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, autofac

**BACKGROUND:**

Our core framework loads all entity framework mappings from itself, the main application and any modules we have installed by using an interface (below):

```
public interface IEntityTypeConfiguration : IDependency
{
}
```

and we have a DbContext in our core framework like this, which loads all the mappings:

```
public class DefaultDbContext : DbContextBase
    {
        private readonly Lazy<IEnumerable<IEntityTypeConfiguration>> configurations;

        public DefaultDbContext(Lazy<IEnumerable<IEntityTypeConfiguration>> configurations)
            : base()
        {
            this.configurations = configurations;
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }

        public DefaultDbContext(string connectionString, Lazy<IEnumerable<IEntityTypeConfiguration>> configurations)
            : base(connectionString)
        {
            this.configurations = configurations;
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            foreach (dynamic typeConfiguration in configurations.Value)
            {
                modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(typeConfiguration);
            }

            Database.SetInitializer(new CreateTablesIfNotExist<DefaultDbContext>());
        }
    }
```

So this way we have a single DbContext for everything.

**PROBLEM:**

We've run into an issue whereby when we dynamically add new modules (which have their own mappings), then EF does not load those mappings ever, even when we are sure that a new instance of `DefaultDbContext` has been created. So, it must be that EF is cacheing the mappings somewhere. Is there some way to clear the cache?

**FINAL NOTE:**

As you may have guessed, we are using an IoC, namely Autofac. If you need any further info, just ask.

Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: Have you taken a look at `System.Data.Entity.Database.Initialize(bool force)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! We found this constructor on the `DbContext` class:

```
public DbContext(string nameOrConnectionString, DbCompiledModel model);
```

I can't share all of the code here, but basically we're creating a new `DbCompiledModel` and passing that in whenever necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The model is cached for performance reasons.

[The following excerpt explains what is going on](http://vbfeeds.com/post.aspx?id=7511)

> Model Caching
>
> There is some cost involved in discovering the model, processing Data Annotations and applying fluent API configuration. To avoid incurring this cost every time a derived DbContext is instantiated the model is cached during the first initialization. The cached model is then re-used each time the same derived context is constructed in the same AppDomain.

This text also mentions a property called `CacheForContextType` but this didn't make it into the final release of EF5.

[This second link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0a794d93-67d1-45de-88dd-cab06267531b/modelbuildercacheforcontexttype-not-available-in-ctp5) provides a glimmer of hope but again is dated before the final release of EF5

> We removed CacheForContextType in CTP5, we originally intended it to be used when folks wanted to use the same context in the same AppDomain with different models. The issue is that it would create the model on every initialization and didn't allow any way to cache a series of models and choose which one to use during each initialization. Model creation is expensive so we wanted to promote a better pattern.
>
> The pattern we recommend is to externally create a ModelBuilder -> DbDatabaseMapping -> DbModel for each model you want to use. The DbModel should be cached and used to create context instances. The ModelBuilder -> DbModel workflow is a little messy and the class names aren't great, they will be tidied up for RTM.

Personally I think you're going to have to find a way of knowing all of your models up front ...